# Any recommendations on watermarking an image in React?

Tags: reactjs

From the scaffold `App`:

```
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />

          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
```

Is there a way to add a watermark to that image?

I have searched npm package site and not much help to identify the right package.

Much appreciated.

Comment: What does this have to do with React? React is not an image processing library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any other npm libraries that process image, doesn't have to be a React component.
Here's one I've been using:
https://libraries.io/npm/react-watermark-component

for example:

```
  watermark([file, '/images/logo-200X255.png'])
    .image(watermark.image.lowerLeft(0.5))
    .then(img =>{

      let holder = this.refs.img_holder;
      holder.appendChild(img);

      this.setState({
        base64:img.src
      });
    });
```

Comment: how to add this in the component?

Comment: In my case I wanted it to add the logo on file drop so : 
                <input type="file"
                       name="fileToUpload"
                       id="fileToUpload"
                       onChange={this._handleImageChange}/> and then passed the file to the function.